# report developer 3.0 date function

Tags: reporting-services

```
=IIF (Fields!LastGiftDate.Value >0, (Format(Cdate (Fields!LastGiftDate.Value),"dd-MM-yyyy")), " ")
```

This above query give me space if there is no date but it will give me #Error if there is a date value. Help.

Comment: Agree with @BhupeshC without the data it is difficult to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `isDate` function to determine if its a date or not. Also `SSRS` `iif` condition are **not short circuited**.

```
=IIF (isDate(Fields!LastGiftDate.Value) 
     ,IIF (isDate(Fields!LastGiftDate.Value), (Format(Cdate (Fields!LastGiftDate.Value),"dd-MM-yyyy")),NOTHING)
     , " ")
```

OR

```
=IIF (isDate(Cdate(Fields!LastGiftDate.Value)) 
     ,IIF (isDate(Fields!LastGiftDate.Value), (Format(Cdate (Fields!LastGiftDate.Value),"dd-MM-yyyy")),NOTHING)
     , " ")
```

OR (Try to run ignoring short cicuit behaviour)

```
=IIF (isDate(Fields!LastGiftDate.Value), (Format(Cdate (Fields!LastGiftDate.Value),"dd-MM-yyyy")), " ")
```

OR

```
=IIF (isDate(Cdate(Fields!LastGiftDate.Value)), (Format(Cdate (Fields!LastGiftDate.Value),"dd-MM-yyyy")), " ")
```

Comment: Thank You isDate works fine. The first one work great.

Comment: Is there anything like isDate, isString? too

Comment: Nope. Why do yo need a isString function?